# Pycharm not using the allocated heap size, causing MemoryError pycharm on read_csv and to_csv (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, memory, pycharm

I am running into a `MemoryError` while trying to read and write large `.csv files in pycharm (using`pandas` lib).

I've tried to change `-Xmx` and `-Xms` parameters in VM Options, however when I inspect the memory usage indicator, I notice that the script is using around 200M (and then crushes with MemoryError) no matter how much memory I've allocated (In that case 1G).

My last try was with these parameters:

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
```

What am I doing wrong, is there another solution for the problem, or maybe steps that I've missed?

Thanks.

Comment: By changing Java VM Options you are changing available memory for IDE, not for a Python process which tries to read `csv` and dies with a `MemoryError`. Try to run it in the terminal outside of PyCharm, you will get the same exception.

Comment: Is there any solution for that?